# Programmatically remove 1 or more files from upload in html5?

Tags: html, upload

I have the below. In `dostuff` I'd like to remove 1 or more files (but not all) from my file uploads.

The only images I accept are `png`, `jpg` and `gif`. `Bmp`, `svg` and etc will get the form rejected.

I do a check in Javascript but I'd like to prompt asking if I can remove the unaccepted files (`bmp`, etc.) and continue. How might I remove the files from upload programmatically?

```
<input type='file' name='uploads[]' multiple="" 
       onchange="dostuff(this);" accept="image/*"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue recently as well. I'm using jQuery to solve my problem, which means it could be translated into vanilla js if you wanted to do that. Here's a code snippet:

```
function clearFileInput(){
   var fileInput = $('#your-file-input-selector');
   var fileInputContainer = fileInput.parent();
   var fileInputClone = fileInput.clone();

   fileInput.remove();
   fileInputContainer.append(fileInputClone);  
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the files as an array, then just manipulate the array as needed to remove unaccepted files.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dostuff(input) {
        var output = 'All Files:<br />';
        var validOutput = '<br />Valid Files:<br />';
        var validFiles = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            if(input.files[i].name.substr(-3, 3) != 'jpg') {
                alert(input.files[i].name + ' is invalid');
            }
            else {
                validFiles.push(input.files[i]);
                validOutput += input.files[i].name;
            }
            output += input.files[i].name + '<br />';
        }
        output += validOutput;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    }
</script>

<input type='file' name='uploads[]' multiple="" onchange="dostuff(this);" accept="image/*"  />
<div id="output"></div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dosboy/mteYj/).

Comment: uhhh you are not removing any files in this code. I just tried modifying input.files and it does not appear to do anything. The server still gets the invalid files even tho my code is ran without errors

Comment: Ya, I was playing with trying to modify input.files, but it's an associative array and for some reason I can't overwrite the values. You might have to use an AJAX method and send the new array of valid files you create instead of the default array of files that gets generated by the control.

Comment: I cant exactly do that. I'll just not automatically do it and refuse to submit. That will probably cause less confusion.

Comment: This is bugging me now. Try http://jsfiddle.net/dosboy/mteYj/4/ . The object type is changing from FileList to Object when I do it this way, so I'm not sure what will happen on the actual submission. But the properties are the same. There doesn't seem to be a way to do a `new FileList()`.

Comment: You don't have a way to test yourself? I just run my asp.net with a dummy page returning the list count and filenames of each file. This doesnt work either. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileList) doesnt mention anything but [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) mentions its read only. Too bad. I guess this is impossible